# О прежних нормах

Tags: старая-грамматика

Читаю вот "Обыкновенную историю" Гончарова и встречаю такие места:

> Однажды летом, в деревне Грач**ах**, у небогатой помещицы Анны Павловны Адуевой, все в доме поднялись с рассветом, начиная с хозяйки до цепной собаки Барбоса.
>
> Когда мимо его проходил лакей, кучер или шмыгала девка, он махал хвостом и тщательно обнюхивал проходящего...
>
> И старый кот, Васька, был к нему, кажется, ласковее, нежели к
>   кому-нибудь в доме.

Меня интересует: так действительно раньше писали и говорили ***повсеместно***?

В первом предложении "деревня Грачи" вроде по нынешним правилам не склоняется, так как это множественное число. Во втором — "мимо его" вместо "мимо **н**его". И, наконец, в третьем предложении "Ваську", мне кажется, сейчас никогда не выделяют запятыми. Последнее особенно интересует! Неужели раньше всегда выделяли?!

И ещё, уже на первых страницах герои успевают несколько раз сказать "пусти прочь". Получается, что раньше так говорили вместо нынешнего "пусти/пропусти (пожалуйста)" с обязательным словом "прочь"?

***Добавление:***

Забыл ещё очень важное:

> Подралась, что ли, ***с своим*** возлюбленным на прощанье?

Меня очень удивляет "с своим" вместо "со своим". Я думал, что только сейчас такие вещи только стали появляться, к сожалению, а ан нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Однажды летом, в деревне Грач**ах**...

Так говорил не только Гончаров. См. у Пушкина (примеры из Нацкорпуса):

*Противу него, для преграждения пути, выслано было Чикою две тысячи человек с четырьмя пушками, которые и ожидали его **в деревне Жукове**.* [А. С. Пушкин. История Пугачева (1833)]

***В деревне Мостах*** (во ста сорока верстах от Самары) случился пожар близ избы, где ночевал Пугачев. [А. С. Пушкин. История Пугачева (1833)]

> Когда **мимо его** проходил лакей...

См. у Пушкина:

*Герцог, проходя **мимо его**, остановился...* [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]

*Однажды, в какой-то праздник, во дворце, проходя **мимо его** в церковь...* [А. С. Пушкин. Table-talk (1831-1836)]

*Они его не заметили и с жаром говорили между собою, проходя **мимо его**.* [А. С. Пушкин. Дубровский (1833)]

*Легким и твердым шагом Германн прошел **мимо его**.* [А. С. Пушкин. Пиковая дама (1833)]

*Германн глядел в щелку: Лизавета Ивановна прошла **мимо его**.* [А. С. Пушкин. Пиковая дама (1833)]

> И, наконец, в третьем предложении "Ваську", мне кажется, сейчас
>   никогда не выделяют запятыми.

Выделяют. См.:

> [§ 63...](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120) Обособляются (**знаками тире или запятыми**) приложения,
>   выраженные именами собственными и относящиеся к нарицательным
>   существительным. Такие приложения имеют уточняющий характер и
>   располагаются после определяемых слов:
>
> *Жене его **— Алевтине —** не очень хотелось летом в деревню* (Шукш.)

===

> Меня очень удивляет "с своим" вместо "со своим". Я думал, что только
>   сейчас такие вещи только стали появляться...

Не сейчас. В первой половине 19-го века *"**с** своим"* употреблялось чаще, чем *"**со** своим"*. Сейчас *"**с** своим"* практически сошло на нет.

См. ***[с своим](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%20%F1%E2%EE%E8%EC)***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. ***[со своим](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EE%20%F1%E2%EE%E8%EC)***:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Меня интересует: так действительно раньше писали и говорили
>   **повсеместно**?

За **повсеместно** не поручусь, но, во всяком случае, в какие-то времена в каких-то местах так и писали, и говорили...

Comment: Спасибо! А напомните, где такой график получить можно?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе на странице "Результаты поиска" (к примеру, при поиске **"с своим"**: http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1+%F1%E2%EE%E8%EC ) найдите строку "**Распределение по годам**". Откройте её. Увидите график: http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%20%F1%E2%EE%E8%EC

Answer (score 1):

1) В деревне Грачи, но в Грачах.

От наличия родового наименования зависит склоняемость топонимов, имеющих форму множественного числа: в городе Великие Луки, в Великих Луках.

2) Правильно: мимо него.

Употребление косвенных падежных форм местоимений он, она, оно, они с начальным Н обязательно после большинства предлогов, факультативно после некоторых предлогов. После части предлогов выступают формы без Н.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/65-n-mestoimenie

3) И старый кот, Васька, был к нему, кажется, ласковее, нежели к кому-нибудь в доме.

Факультативное обособление со значением уточнения, выделяется паузами при чтении, но можно писать "И старый кот Васька...", приложение + имя собственное.

4) Выражение "пусти прочь" любил употреблять Гончаров, у других авторов оно не часто встречается, судя по Нацкорпусу:

Пусти прочь: надо полотенце достать. [И. А. Гончаров. Обыкновенная история (1847)]

Да пусти прочь, негде ступить: протянул ноги-то! [И. А. Гончаров. Обыкновенная история (1847)]

Comment: Вера, я спрашиваю про то, как было ***тогда*** правильно, когда Гончаров писал. То, что сейчас так правильно, как Вы написали, я и так понимаю.

Comment: Здесь две возможности. Во-первых, можно предположить, что вряд ли стали печатать книги без соблюдения норм орфографии того времени (или хотя бы традиций написания). Во-вторых, можно попробовать ознакомиться с правилами, действующими во времена Гончарова. Но считается, что СИСТЕМНАЯ русская орфография начинается с Грота  (В 1885 г. вышло в свет "Русское правописание", выдержавшее 9 изданий), а  "Обыкновенная история" написана в 1847 году. Кроме того, по указанной тематике нормы, скорее всего,  часто менялись, если и до настоящего времени нет единого решения.